# Need help with child pages displaying as individual pages

Tags: child-pages, support, post-type-support

We could really use some help, guidance, or any available resources related to our issue.

On our WordPress website (using the free version of Elementor, Sinatra theme), we have encountered an problem with child pages.

We created a child page with the
URL: sreesrehab.com/locations/anna-nagar, which is subpage of the "locations" parent page.

However, WordPress is displaying this child page as a standalone page at URL : sreesrehab.com/anna-nagar/. This has resulted in duplicate content.

We need this page to only be accessible as a child page under "locations," not as an independent page.

If anyone could offer assistance, resources, or if you know where we could find relevant help, it would be helpful.

Thank you!